# Type a text in JTextArea from another class

Tags: java

I have a problem with updating a textArea from another class. 
I need a textArea to show a text while pressing a button. 
So when I press a buton I make a method actionPerformed() in ParceListener to print a text in a textArea which is located in MainFormAppearance class. But it doesn't do that. Could you please help me?

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("Title");

    MainFormAppearance demo = new MainFormAppearance();
    jFrame.setContentPane(demo.createContentPanel());

    jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(jFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jFrame.setSize(400,300);
    jFrame.setVisible(true);

}
}
```

MainFormAppearance

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MainFormAppearance {

public JPanel totalGui;
public JTextArea frame;
public JLabel blueLabel;
public JButton parceButton;
public JButton mailButton;
public ParceListener parceListener;

public JPanel createContentPanel(){

    totalGui = new JPanel();
    frame = new JTextArea();
    blueLabel = new JLabel("Some program");
    parceButton = new JButton("Button 1");
    mailButton = new JButton("Button 2");
    parceListener = new ParceListener();
    totalGui.setLayout(null);

    //set program window
    blueLabel.setLocation(10,10);
    blueLabel.setSize(400,20);
    blueLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    blueLabel.setForeground(Color.blue);
    totalGui.add(blueLabel);

    //set Button 1
    parceButton.setLocation(270, 50);
    parceButton.setSize(100,30);
    totalGui.add(parceButton);
    //Pressing the Button 1
    parceButton.addActionListener(parceListener);

    //set Button 2
    mailButton.setLocation(270, 100);
    mailButton.setSize(100, 30);
    totalGui.add(mailButton);

    frame.setLocation(20, 115);
    frame.setSize(200, 15);
    totalGui.add(frame);

    totalGui.setOpaque(true);
    return totalGui;
}

public void setTextArea(String myString){
    frame.append(myString);
}


}
```

ParceListener

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class ParceListener implements ActionListener {

public String text = "some text";
MainFormAppearance mainFormAppearance = new MainFormAppearance();

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    mainFormAppearance.setTextArea(text);

}

}
```

It shows NullPointerException at frame.append(myString); in MainFormAppearance class.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `MainFormAppearance mainFormAppearance = new MainFormAppearance();` in your `ParceListener` is creating a new instance of `MainFormAppearance` which has nothing to do with what is actually been presented on the screen.

You need some way to return information back to the main UI from `ParceListener`.

This is best accomplished using an Observer Pattern, where `ParceListener` generates notifications/events when something changes.  It shouldn't care about "who" is interested, only that they are.

Let's start with a simple interface...

```
public interface ParceObserver {
    public void parceChanged(String text);
}
```

`MainFormAppearance` can now implement this `interface` and make what ever updates it needs.

```
public class MainFormAppearance implements ParceObserver {
    //...

    public void parceChanged(String text) {
        frame.append("\n" + text);
    }
}
```

Then thing here is, `ParceListener`, doesn't care what happens after it's posted the notification.

Now, you just need to pass an instance of `ParceObserver` to `ParceListener`

```
parceListener = new ParceListener(this);
```

And update `ParceListener` to make use of it...

```
public class ParceListener implements ActionListener {

    private ParceObserver observer;

    public String text = "some text";

    public ParceListener(ParceObserver observer) {
        this.observer = observer;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (observer == null) {
           return null;
        }
        observer.parceChanged(text);
    }

}
```

Now it's nicely de-coupled and re-usable.

And, if someone tells you to just pass a reference of the `JTextArea` or `MainFormAppearance` to `ParceListener`, please don't listen to them.  It's inappropriate, tightly couples your code and exposes the components to the risk of been modified in ways you never intended them to be